# CSS targeting iPad Pro 12.9 in Portrait not working

Tags: css, ipad

We have the following CSS which works for all iPads except for `iPad Pro 12.9`:

```
/* ----------- iPad 3, 4 and Pro 9.7" ----------- */
/* Portrait and Landscape */
  
@media only screen
and (min-device-width: 768px)
and (max-device-width: 1024px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    .pp-button-1 {margin-bottom: 10px;)
}
    
/* ----------- iPad Pro 10.5" ----------- */
/* Portrait */

@media only screen
  and (min-device-width: 834px)
  and (max-device-width: 834px)
  and (orientation: portrait)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    .pp-button-1 {margin-bottom: 0;)
}
    
/* ----------- iPad Pro 11 2018 " ----------- */
/* Portrait */
    
@media only screen
and (min-width: 834px)
and (orientation: portrait) {
    .pp-button-1 {margin-bottom: 0;}
}

/* ----------- iPad Pro 11 2020 " ----------- */

@media only screen
and (min-width: 834px)
and (orientation: portrait) {
    .pp-button-1 {margin-bottom: 0;}
}

/* ----------- iPad Pro 11 2021 " ----------- */
    
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
    only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
    only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
    only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    .pp-button-1 {margin-bottom: 0;}
}

/* ----------- iPad Pro 9 " ----------- */
/* Portrait */
    
@media only screen
and (min-width: 1024px)
and (orientation: portrait) {
    .pp-button-1 {margin-bottom: 10px;}
}

/* ----------- iPad Pro 12.9" ----------- */
/* Portrait */
  
@media only screen
and (min-device-width: 1024px)
and (max-device-height: 1366px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
and (orientation: portrait) {
    .pp-button-1 {margin-bottom: 0;}
}
```

Our site https://mandoemedia.com displays with a gap above one of the buttons on an iPad Pro 12.9:

[image]

which is produced by CSS:

```
.pp-button-1 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Note the last CSS rule which targets iPad Pro 12.9 taken from [this page](https://fjorgedigital.com/insights/blog/how-can-i-target-only-an-ipad-pro/):

```
/* ----------- iPad Pro 12.9" ----------- */
/* Portrait */
  
@media only screen
and (min-device-width: 1024px)
and (max-device-height: 1366px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
and (orientation: portrait) {
    .pp-button-1 {margin-bottom: 0;}
}
```

However this `margin-bottom: 0;` is not taking effect.

**EDIT:** What *is* taking effect is:

```
/* ----------- iPad 3, 4 and Pro 9.7" ----------- */
/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width: 768px)
and (max-device-width: 1024px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    .pp-button-1 {margin-bottom: 10px;)
}
```

Why is the `iPad 3, 4 and Pro 9.7"` media query active for an `iPad Pro 12.9`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the below should work, attaching screenshots.

```css
.padding-20-20.mobile-centered {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That's better code, but I've edited my question to show that the wrong media query is active for `iPad Pro 12.9`.

Comment: I used flexbox for all media queries which fixed the problem. I can award the bounty in 4 hours.